# What are the various ways to express 'or' and when are they appropriate?

Tags: grammar, nuances, particles, conjunctions

I'd like to get an idea of when it is appropriate to use different expressions for expressing disjunction (of the inclusive AND exclusive variety).

「AとBとCの中で...」、「どちら」、and 「か」 come to mind, but I think they have situational usage (that I'm not entirely aware of). 「か」 seems somewhat awkward, 「どちら」 is limited to a decision between two things, and so forth. How would an inclusive or be expressed ('A or B' as opposed to 'either A or B')?

Comment: Welcome to JLU! This is a good fundamental question. I'm surprised no one asked this here before >___<

Comment: Your `AとBの中で` is not completely grammatical. `中で` is used for more than two alternatives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Natural languages usually have exclusive disjunction. In order to express inclusive disjunction, you usually have to add some materials to exclusive disjunction.

- Exclusive disjunction between two things

  > A か B (の({うち/間}の)どちらか(一つ/一方))
  >   'between A or B'
- Exclusive disjunction among more than two things

  > A か B, (か) C (の({うち/間/中}の)どれか(一つ))
  >   'among A, B, or C'
- Inclusive disjunction between two things

  > A か B の({うち/間}の)少なくとも{一つ/一方}
  >   'A and/or B'
- Inclusive disjunction among more than two things

  > A か B, (か) C の({うち/間/中}の)少なくとも一つ
  >   'A, B, and/or C'

---

Since the OP seems to be having trouble with the notation, I will expand the first one so that there is no parentheses and braces:

- Exclusive disjunction between two things

> A か B
>   A か B のどちらか
>   A か B のどちらか一つ
>   A か B のどちらか一方
>   A か B のうちのどちらか
>   A か B の間のどちらか
>   A か B のうちのどちらか一つ
>   A か B のうちのどちらか一方
>   A か B の間のどちらか一つ
>   A か B の間のどちらか一方

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble understanding your use of parentheses and braces. Could you explain briefly ^^;?

Comment: @DylanLukes Parentheses mean optional. For example, A(B)C means ABC and AC are possible. A(B(C)D)E means ABCDE, ABDE, AE are possible. Braces with slash mean alternatives. For example, A{B/C}D means ABD and ACD are possible. This is a commonly accepted notation.

Comment: Also, is か always appropriate? Could these all be used both in spoken and written language? Is there a more appropriate form for formal situations?... etc.

Comment: @DlyanLukes They are fine. If you want to be more formal, there is `または`, `もしくは`, `あるいは` as istrasci suggests. But I feel the latter two are only used for exclusive disjunctions.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple more examples for exclusive that I can think of:

- AそしてまたB
- AまたはB
- AそれともB
- A或【ある】いはB

Comment: How did you do the furigana? Is this a new feature?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Add `{furigana}` after the kanji, e.g. `漢字.{かんじ}` (without the dot).

Comment: That's not how I did it.  I just put that hiragana inside these thick brackets, like 【あいうえお】.  Speaking of which, is there any way to turn this feature off?  I hate furigana.